# Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web

I have a site that as far a I know is not using http or https. It is just 
  `examplewebsite.co`
I am not receiving any analytics from my Google Analytics account. Any thoughts on if the website is a problem or a reason I am not receiving anything?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find out whether your analytics code is working. Go to your Analytics account >> Admin >>Tracking code

On top of the page, next to Tracking ID, you can see the status of the traffic. Click the "send traffic button".

If the analytics code has been installed correctly, your website pops up. Else, check the analytics code in your website.